# How to build several libraries using conan on windows?

Tags: conan

I try to install dependences using "conan install .." from build folder.
conanfile.txt:

```
 [requires]

 boost/1.79.0

 gtest/cci.20210126

 qt/6.3.0@#67d45f5425575521592e68cf091d1c27

 [generators]
 CMakeDeps
 CMakeToolchain
```

And i get an error
CMake Error at .conan/conanbuildinfo.cmake:448 (message):
Incorrect 'Visual Studio'.  Toolset specifies compiler as 'MSVC' but CMake   detected 'GNU'
then i create new config file wingw64

```
[build_requires]
[settings]
    os=Windows
    os_build=Windows
    arch=x86_64
    arch_build=x86_64
    compiler=gcc
    compiler.version=8.2
    compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
    build_type=Release
[options]
[env]
```

and use "conan install .. --profile=mingw64" and get an error earlier (look at screen). [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIgiH.png)

Comment: You are mixing generators. The declared ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain`` generators do not create ``conanbuildinfo.cmake`` at all. So it seems there is some missing or incorrectly reported.

Comment: Also, do not post an image like that with the output. Instead, copy and paste the text. Reading that text you can find some details, explaining that there are no precompiled binaries for that configuration in ConanCenter, and you need to build them from source. I'd recommend using Visual Studio compiler in Windows, it is in general way better tested for recipes in ConanCenter than MinGW.

Comment: For the ``conan search brotli/1.0.9@ --table=table.html -r=conancenter`` command, you need to add the trailing ``@``. In any case, the explanation is that ConanCenter is not building MinGW binaries, and you should build them from source, or use VisualStudio compiler.

Comment: I stil get the same message "C:\Users\Vladimir\Desktop\CodeNames\build\conanbuildinfo.cmake:2787: error: Incorrect 'Visual Studio'.  Toolset specifies compiler as 'MSVC' but CMake detected 'GNU' build/conanbuildinfo.cmake:2354 (conan_check_compiler) CMakeLists.txt:22 (conan_basic_setup)" I run cmake project from  Qt.

Comment: That is impossible with the code that you are reporting above. The ``conanbuildinfo.cmake`` is NOT generated by the ``CMakeDeps`` and ``CMakeToolchain``. That file shouldn't exist at all. There is something that you are not detailing. You need to post your ``CMakeLists.txt`` and the exact commands you are typing.

Comment: @drodri Here conanfile.txt https://pastebin.com/KsC91rdL  
Here CMakeLists.txt https://pastebin.com/pkjPNp01  
Here conan profile https://pastebin.com/HgWVsFX7 named msvc  
I use command conan install .. --profile=msvc
from build directory.

Comment: Then, as a first thing, the conanfile.txt you are reporting above is not the same as the one you provide in pastebin.com/KsC91rdL, which uses ``[generators]cmake``. Please update the question code, because that would be leading to confusion to all readers. The error you are reporting above is with ``--profile=mingw64`` profile, but the profile you are pasting is a ``msvc`` one, not a mingw one. So basically nothing matches, what you report above and what you are pasting in pastebin are different things.

Comment: I'd recommend to put everything in a git repo, including a ``build.py`` script that would reproduce the issue and submit to https://github.com/conan-io/conan/issues, including the full terminal output as text, not as a captured image.